# How to optimize cache performance?

Tags: c, caching

I have written a C code using arrays to understand behavior of cache on my intel i7 8750 with L1d = 32k, L2 = 258k, L3: 912k with line size 64 Bytes and Set Size = 8.[The trend I see for my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUbwa.png)
I am trying to understand the output that i get from my code's output. 
What else can be done in my code to ensure that I get minimum cache misses if LRU is cache's replacement policy ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

#define BILLION 1000000000L

struct student
{
    char name[64];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

     int m, i, p;
     char* n;
     char mn[64];
     u_int64_t diff; 
     struct timespec start, end; 
     m = strtol(argv[1], &n, 0);

    struct student* arr_student = malloc(m * sizeof(struct student));

    for(u_int64_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {      
         strcpy(arr_student[i].name, "abc");
    }

     /* 100 runs to ensure cache warmup and linear access time calculation*/ 

    for (int j = 0; j<100; j++){        

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &start);
        for(u_int64_t i = 0; i < m; i+=8){
            strcpy(mn,arr_student[i].name);
     if(i < (m-8)){
    strcpy(mn,arr_student[i+1].name);
    strcpy(mn,arr_student[i+2].name);
    strcpy(mn,arr_student[i+3].name);
    strcpy(mn,arr_student[i+4].name);
    strcpy(mn,arr_student[i+5].name);
    strcpy(mn,arr_student[i+6].name);
    strcpy(mn,arr_student[i+7].name);
    }
    }
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &end);
} 

diff = BILLION * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;

printf("Time take for linear read operation only: %llu nanoseconds\n", (long long unsigned int) diff / 8 );

free(arr_student);

return 0;
}
```

I see a trend where as I grow the array size, execution time of loop executing stride of 8, takes more and more time. I am expecting it to stay constant and only increase when CPU has to go look in L2 i.e. when Array size grows beyond what L1 can fit. I expect to see a result like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=cache+performance+trend+l1+l2&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS831US831&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9jqqApYrgAhXYFjQIHR39BtwQ_AUIDygC&biw=1280&bih=913#imgrc=5JVNAazx3drZvM:

Why do I get reverse trend when I divide diff by m ? i fail to understand this trend.

Please help ?

Comment: I do not really get your question. If you increase m, the number of iterations in your loop will grow linearly.. At least, you should divide your time by m (and insure that you loop always exactly m times). Also, measure the time of 100 iterations to increase measure accuracy. But do not expect spectacular effects as you fetch your data in a very deterministic and cache friendly way, and intel has an efficient  prefetcher.

Comment: Edited the code to divide the time by 8 to ensure that the time I get is per array element (64 Bytes). I grow m to check access time per 64 bytes for an array that doesn't fit in L1 and CPU has to go to L2 to find those elements. In that case I expect to see a good amount of difference in access time per 64 bytes.

Comment: You are looping over m elements (exactly the largest multiple of 8<m). So your time grows with m, cache effects or not.

Comment: Thanks for your input. is there nothing else that I can do to optimize the code here ? something to see a trend like this here: https://www.google.com/search?q=cache+performance+trend+l1+l2&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS831US831&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9jqqApYrgAhXYFjQIHR39BtwQ_AUIDygC&biw=1280&bih=913#imgrc=5JVNAazx3drZvM:

Comment: Why do I reverse trend when I divide diff by m ? i fail to understand this trend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some useful tricks about memory alignment and code optimization:

- [The Lost Art of Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/)
- [Optimization of Computer Programs in C](http://icps.u-strasbg.fr/~bastoul/local_copies/lee.html)

and in general, code optimization is a matter of time and experience.